# javaFX TableView not updating even though the data List is updated

Tags: javafx, tableview, refresh

EDITED: I have created and TableView with an cellValueFactory with a PropertyValueFactory but when I then update the ObservableList representing the data of the TableView, my TableView will not update. I am sure that the new List created by readNctsvorgaenge() is updated and contains and additional Item.This is implemented with mvvmfx -> moodel view viewmodel

This is the FXML File...

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cuscus.ui.vorgangnctsmonitor.MonitorNctsvorgang">
    <children>
        <TableView fx:id="nctsvorgaengeTable"
            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="175.0" text="%common.Bezugsnummer">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="bezugsnummer" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

the controller part of the view:

```
    public class MonitorNctsvorgang implements FxmlView<MonitorNctsvorgangViewModel> {
        @FXML
        private TableView<MonitorNctsvorgangTableViewModel> nctsvorgaengeTable;
        @InjectViewModel
        private MonitorNctsvorgangViewModel viewModel;

        public void initialize() {
            nctsvorgaengeTable.setItems(viewModel.getNctsvorgaenge());
            viewModel.selectedTableRowProperty().bind(nctsvorgaengeTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
            viewModel.setOnSelect(vm -> nctsvorgaengeTable.getSelectionModel().select(vm));
        }
    }
```

and the DataModel for the TableView is...

```
public class MonitorNctsvorgangTableViewModel {
   private final Nctsvorgang nctsvorgang;

   public MonitorNctsvorgangTableViewModel(Nctsvorgang nctsvorgang) {
      this.nctsvorgang = nctsvorgang;
   }

   public String getBezugsnummer() {
      return nctsvorgang.getBezugsnummer();
   }
}
```

my viewmodel

```
    public class MonitorNctsvorgangViewModel implements ViewModel {
       @InjectScope
       private NctsvorgangDetailScope   detailScope;
       @Inject
       private CusCusDao                cuscusDao;

       private final ObservableList<MonitorNctsvorgangTableViewModel>   vorgaenge = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

       public ObservableList<MonitorNctsvorgangTableViewModel> getNctsvorgaenge() {
            return vorgaenge;
       }

       public void initialize() {
           updateNctsvorgaenge();
       }

       public void onNctsvorgangUpdateEvent(@Observes NctsvorgangUpdatedEvent event) {
           updateNctsvorgaenge();
       }      

       private void updateNctsvorgaenge() {
            final List<Nctsvorgang> allVorgaenge = cuscusDao.readNctsvorgaenge();
           vorgaenge.clear();
            allVorgaenge.forEach(vorgang -> vorgaenge.add(new MonitorNctsvorgangTableViewModel(vorgang)));
       }
   }

    Nctsvorgang {
        String bezugsnummer;
    //getter setter here
    }
```

So I wonder why is my TableView not updating/refreshing, when I read a different ObservaleList into the ObservaleList.
I am following an example (mvvmFX contacts example) and I am pretty sure the code is the same as in the example. I am stuck with this for a couple of days and Googlesearch did not resolve my question and it drives me nuts. Sorry if double Post but I am tired of looking for an answer:/
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a [MCVE] that shows the issue. There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted, but there are lots of key things that are missing (injecting the table view into the controller, connecting the table view with the observable list, etc etc). If you create a MCVE, you guarantee that the code you post includes your error(s).

Comment: I 'll be setting up a github tomorrow with a maven project, too tired today;)

Comment: No, don't post external links to the code. As I said in my previous comment, create a [MCVE] that has just enough (and no more than is necessary) to demonstrate the problem, and post that example directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found my Problem, my ViewModel was not Annotaed @Singleton